# How to specify what worksheet to use with find/with

Tags: excel, vba

I want to search a range A1-A99 in a certain sheet (wsCaseinfo) for the word Overview. I get a 1004 error on the 'with' line.

The code is part of a larger code using 3 different sheets in 2 different files. Code cycles through 100 files, so something efficient would be appreciated. Many thanks for your help.

```
With wsCaseinfo.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(99, 1))
    Set cellx = .Find(what:="Overview", LookAt:=xlPart)
End With
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to append the `Cells()` with the parent sheet:

```
With wsCaseinfo.Range(wsCaseinfo.Cells(1, 1), wsCaseinfo.Cells(99, 1))
```

Other wise the `Cells()` will refer to the active sheet and not the same sheet as the `Range()`.

You can also nest a `With` in the first `With`

```
With wsCaseinfo
    With .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(99, 1))
        Set cellx = .Find(what:="Overview", LookAt:=xlPart)
    End With
End With
```

Comment: Thanks Scott for your quick and perfect answer, much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

```
With Sheets("wsCaseinfo").Range(Sheets("wsCaseinfo").Cells(1, 1), Sheets("wsCaseinfo").Cells(99, 1))
    Set cellx = .Find(What:="Overview", LookAt:=xlPart)
End With
```

<strike>Three</strike> Four ways of referring to a sheet:

1. The name (as above)
2. The index (eg. `Sheets(4)`)
3. The codename (eg. `Sheet4`)
4. Using a variable eg.

   ```
   Dim MySheet As Worksheet
   Set MySheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet4")
   ```

   then using

   ```
   MySheet.Cells()
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

**EDITED VERSION**

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim rngToSearch As Range
    Dim Result As Range

    Set rngToSearch = wsCaseinfo.Range("A1:A99")

    Set Result = rngToSearch.Find(What:="Overview", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)

    If Not Result Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "The word ""Overview"" appears in:" _
            & vbNewLine & "Row " & Result.Row _
            & vbNewLine & "Column " & Result.Column _
            & vbNewLine & "Address " & Result.Address
    Else
        MsgBox "The word ""Overview"" does not exist in range " & rngToSearch.Address & "."
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: `Result.Row` will fail if `Overview` was not found. Test `Result` for `Nothing` to make it solid.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ is find it more useful to use Nothing to make it solid.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `Cells()`, you must qualify.  Instead:

```
Sub luxation()
    Dim cellx As Range, wsCaseinfo As Worksheet
    Set wsCaseinfo = Sheets("Sheet1")

    With wsCaseinfo.Range("A1:A99")
        Set cellx = .Find(what:="Overview", LookAt:=xlPart)
        MsgBox cellx.Address
    End With
End Sub
```

[image]

Change the `Set` statement to suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

## Find in Worksheet

### Shortest

> ```
> With wsCaseInfo
>     Set cellx = .Range("A1:A99").Find("Overview", , xlValues, xlPart)
> End With
> ```

### Short

```
With wsCaseInfo

    Set cellx = .Range("A1:A99").Find("Overview", , xlValues, xlPart)

    If Not cellx Is Nothing Then
        Debug.Print cellx.Address
      Else
        Debug.Print "Cell range not found."
    End If

End With
```

### Long

```
Sub FindInWorksheet()

    Const cSheet As String = "Sheet1"

    Dim wsCaseInfo As Worksheet
    Dim cellx As Range

    Set wsCaseInfo = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(cSheet)

    With wsCaseInfo
        ' Full
        'Set cellx = .Range("A1:A99").Find("Overview", .Range("A99"), _
                xlValues, xlPart, xlByColumns, xlNext, False)
        ' Preferable
        'Set cellx = .Range("A1:A99").Find("Overview", , _
                xlValues, xlPart, xlByColumns)
        ' Minimal
        Set cellx = .Range("A1:A99").Find("Overview", , xlValues, xlPart)

        If Not cellx Is Nothing Then
            Debug.Print cellx.Address
          Else
            Debug.Print "Cell range not found."
        End If

    End With

End Sub
```

### Find Method Reminder

- The 1st argument, **What**, contains the data to search for and is **required**. All other arguments are optional.
- By omitting the second argument, **After**, your search starts from
  `A2` and ends with `A1` which is often preferable because we have
  headers in the first row. But to start the search from `A1` and end
  with `A99`, you would have to set the **After** parameter to `"A99"`.
- The 3rd, 4th and 5th arguments, **LookIn**, **LookAt** and
  **SearchOrder**, are **SAVED** each time a `Find` is 'performed'.

  - By setting the **LookIn** argument's parameter to `xlValues` you prevent possible
    searching in formulas (or comments).
  - **LookAt** is correctly set to `xlPart` to find values of the **What** parameter (`Overview`) in cells where it is only a part of them e.g. `Product Overview` or `Overview of Parts` will be found. Or is it?
  - **SearchOrder** can safely be omitted, since we're searching in a one-column range.
- The 6th argument, **SearchDirection**, is by *default* `xlNext` which
  is used in the code and can therefore be safely omitted.
- The 7th argument, **MatchCase**, is by *default* `False` to find `OverView` or `ovErView` which is probably no issue here.